# Dynamically removing form elements in Drupal 6

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, drupal-6, cck

Is it possible to alter a CCK form dynamically (via jQuery) so I can remove certain elements?

I want my user to be able to click something (checkbox or link) which will then remove two or more text fields. And of course they should not just be removed from the DOM it should also be possible to remove required fields without getting an error message when I submit the form. Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

If you wanted to alter the output server side, you could do it so in a module implementing the hook_form_alter, just make sure that your module is executed after CCK.